# Problema para hospedar aplicação angular

Tags: angularjs, hospedagem, host

Sou iniciante com angular e estou querendo hospedar uma aplicação simples no uol host para estudar.

o servidor está funcionando mas não consigo redirecionar para a página inicial da minha aplicação.

[image: Minha hospedagem default]

O código do server.js que está rodando é esse:

```html
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World 2\n");
});

// Listen on port 8080, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(process.env.PORT || config.port);

console.log("Listening on port: " + (process.env.PORT || config.port));
```

Quero apontar para meu index.html
[image: Minha hospedagem]

Acredito que eu tenha que alterar algo no server.js para transformar meu index.html na página inicial, como devo fazer?